# Revolution slider in different browersers

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I was designing few banners on my website in Firefox then after completing it, I notice that the texts and some buttons are different in Firefox than Chrome, like buttons are rounded in Chrome which I wanted look like, but in Firefox is square. Also, texts are in different styles and smaller in Chrome than Firefox.

How can I handle with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ .  It can remove the differences between how browser display various elements.  Then add your CSS to format how you want and all browsers should then have the same look.